# I am unable print colored text

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am unable to print the text in Orange colored.I identified the edges of the image and then printed a text on it.

```
%matplotlib inline
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('ind_maharashtra.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,20)
cv2.imwrite('Edged_img.jpg',edges)
#plt.subplot(121)
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img.jpg',0)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img1,'JAI MAHARASHTRA !!',(70,150), font, 0.7,(255,69,0),2,cv2.LINE_8)
cv2.imshow('Maharashtra Map',img1)
#cv2.imshow('Maharashtra Map',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Whichever RGB value I use , the text gets printed in grayscale.The RGB value I have passed is of orange color

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the image on which you are trying to draw ( the image named `img1`) is a gray-scale image since the 2nd argument of `cv2.imread` is `0` in the following line:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img.jpg',0)
```

You have 2 options to fix this issue. First one is to load the image as a color image as follows:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img.jpg')
```

Alternatively, if you want your canvas to have a *gray-ish* look, you can just replicate the single channel to form a 3 channel image as follows:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img.jpg', 0)
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your jpg in grayscale, so you will only be able to write grayscale to img1

[OpenCV Imread docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image)
[image]

change this line

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img.jpg',0)
```

to

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img.jpg',1)
```

As you can see from the above linked docs, using these numbers is OK but you are actually setting a flag, so you could use the flag definition to make your code clearer. Coincidentally, if you had used the flags you would likely not have had this issue.

You can change your line to

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Edged_img', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Look how much clearer, and understandable that is. Especially when you come back to this code/hand it over to another developer in a few months time.

Comment: IMHO this answer would be a LOT better if it actually discouraged OP from using magic numbers. Had it said `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` in the first place, it would have be much more obvious why there's no colour.

Comment: @DanMašek I generally agree, but I didn't really provide any opinion except "Read the docs" which say "use the flags, or feel free to use these numbers". I have added the suggested.